# Rails 3: production environment change locale but doesn't translate text [w/ custom fallbacks]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, production-environment, rails-i18n

I have this app in which I use a bunch of locales (which are adjusted to be more suited to the domain of the app, ex: instead of using es-MX, I just use mx as locale)

And I have configured the fallbacks in application.rb

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
config.i18n.fallbacks = {
  # sites
  'cl' => 'es',
  'mx' => 'es',
  'lat' => 'es',
  'br' => 'en',
  'us' => 'en',

  # lang
  'es' => 'en',
  'pt' => 'br',
}
```

And I set the locale by url ex: localhost:3001/cl (for chilean locale)

here's my code in app_controller

```
 before_filter :set_locale

  private

  def set_locale
    if supported_locale?(params[:locale])
      I18n.locale = params[:locale]
    end
  end
```

And my routes

```
  # public urls for sites
  scope '/:locale' do

    # index
    match '/' => 'main#index', via: :get, as: :site
  end
```

So, the thing is when I am in production I have localhost:3001/cl
and it calls the _logo.cl.html.erb partial and the locale printed in the console it's *cl*.
But the text are still in english. And in development everything works fine. Anyone has any idea about this?

I'll leave a couple of images

production/us
[image: production/us]
production/cl
[image: production/cl]
development/cl
[image: development/cl]

Answer (score 3):

The thing was that the `production.rb` file define

```
# Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to       
# the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
```

overwriting the custom fallback rules that I had defined in `application.rb` and I just remove those lines and the problem was solved